# Mysql only select row with existing parent

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, left-join

**I have this query:**

```
SELECT id,id1,title FROM tablename 
    LEFT JOIN tablename AS parent 
        ON tablename .id1 = parent.id 
        WHERE parent.id is NULL
```

What I try to achieve is that only rows are shown from which no parent exist.

**Table layout and content**

```
id    id1(parent)    title
1     0              parent
2     1              child1
3     1              child2
4     100            orphan
5     1              child3
6     1              child4
```

In this example I would query all but leave out the one which has no existing parent row (row 4, the orphan, parent 100 which does not exists in tablename).

Comment: It does have a parent. The parent record of the orphan row has id=100. That should be `NULL`. Also, the namings are way off. Using `table` as a table name (being a restricted word) is especially annoying...

Comment: table is a pseudoname, not the real name offcourse, I changed the question to make it a bit more clearly.

Comment: you mean all rows which have either id1 IS NULL or if id1 has other value ,that value is not there as id in the table?

Comment: Your  query works fine. . Your data is wrong I guess. Because you are matching parent ids..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
SELECT child.id,child.id1,child.name 
FROM table AS child --alias names, as column names would be ambiguous
LEFT JOIN table AS parent 
    ON table.id1 = parent.id 
WHERE parent.id is NULL  -- only no parent!
```

Shows the *orphans*. To get all non-orphans

```
SELECT child.id,child.id1,child.name 
FROM table AS child
JOIN table AS parent -- JOIN takes care of getting only the records with parents 
    ON child.id1 = parent.id
```

Why does this work this way? `LEFT JOIN` is for joining tables, where we would like to receive rows of the left hand side table, where the right hand side table does not have a record that fulfills the join criteria. The columns pertaining to the right hand side table would all be `NULL` in that case. By using a simple `JOIN`, only those rows are shown from the first table, that have a record in the table on right hand side of the join.

**Why did you get wrong result**

The column names can get to be ambiguous when joining tables, and always do so when self-joining... You have to distinguish between them, by using alias names.

**Ideas to consider**

Maintainability. Keep this in mind, even for examples. Name your objects properly: `table` is not a descriptive name (and is a keyword too), use `PERSON` instead. For columns, `id1` is not a descriptive name - use `PARENT_ID` instead...

Comment: This one helpt me a lot by explaining the issues with my query. Thanks a lot for this clear and understandable suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks correct, except you need table aliases for the columns in the `select`:

```
SELECT table.id, table.id1, table.name
FROM table LEFT JOIN
     table AS parent 
     ON table.id1 = parent.id 
WHERE parent.id is NULL ;
```

The problem is that both `table` and `parent` have the same columns.  The engine doesn't know which you really want without the table alias.

Comment: Good suggestion! Forgot that!

Answer (score 1):

> What I try to achieve is that only rows are shown from which no parent exist.

Surely this is the EXACT OPPOSITE of:

> Mysql only select row with exisiting parent

The query in your question seems to exactly meet your requirement `only rows are shown from which no parent exist`

If you want the opposite of this , use an inner join and lose the where clause:

```
SELECT id,id1,name FROM table 
INNER JOIN table AS parent 
    ON table.id1 = parent.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT id,id1,title
FROM table 
WHERE id1 IS NULL OR id1 NOT IN(SELECT id FROM table);
```